# Move dynamic plot inside DynamicModule

Tags: plotting, graphics, dynamic

I am trying to understand `Dynamic` a bit better for some classroom presentations, so I tried to make a dynamic list plot. As far as I can tell, this still requires repeatedly replotting the entire plot, but I think superceded plots can immediately be garbage collected. (Right?)

Anyway, consider the following simple example, which I believe captures my core considerations. (The `Pause` just allows enough time to watch the animation.)

```
traj = Sin@Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 50]  (* the trajectory to plot *)
Dynamic@tmax
Dynamic[ListPlot[traj[[;; tmax]],
  DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi*tmax/50}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}], None]
Do[FinishDynamic[]; Pause[0.01]; tmax = n, {n, 1, 51}]
```

1. Is this basically correct as an approach to my problem of dynamic plotting?
2. Does `ListAnimate` have advantages over this approach, aside from this approach a. introducing an otherwise unneeded global variable and b. not being able (afaict) to save the animation?
3. How can I do this inside a `DynamicModule`, to avoid introducing dynamic global variables?

**Edit:**

A stated in the question, a key goal here is to better understand `Dynamic` and relations. For the simple example above, `Animate` works just fine.

Comment: why not just use Manipulate? It makes everything much simpler.

Comment: Or `Animate[]`.

Comment: @Nasser A stated in the question, a key goal here is to better understand `Dynamic` and relations. For the example, `Animate` works just fine.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Just to elaborate a little bit, the above approach is easily adapted to update a plot after each point-producing iteration.

Comment: I know. But you said also `understand Dynamic a bit better for some classroom presentations` so I took it as your end goal is to make classroom presentations. If this is the goal, then Manipulate is much better. But ofcourse you can do all that using direct Dynamic module. It is just harder. I prefer to use the easier method when given a choice :)

Comment: `Animate` and `Animator` have the option [`DisplayAllSteps`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DisplayAllSteps.html), which forces an update after each iteration. -- Generally, though, your approach is "correct." You've noted a desire to avoid the use of global variables already, and I would add that driving the animation with a `Do[]` loop instead of a traditional control (as found in `Manipulate[]` and `Animate[]`) is likely to prove inconvenient.

Comment: Is the primary difficulty that you don't want to have to replot things? That's an annoying problem to solve but can be done with some cleverness. Also `ListAnimate` animations can 100% be saved (use `Export["path/to/file.gif", ..., AnimationRepetitions->Infinity]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Using the OP's `Do[]` loop inside a button:

```
    DynamicModule[{tmax = 0, traj, done},
     traj = Sin@Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 50] ; (*the trajectory to plot*)
     Column[{
       Row[{
         "tmax = ", Dynamic@tmax,
         Button["Start",
          Do[
           tmax = n;
           FinishDynamic[];
           Pause[0.01],
           {n, 1, 51}],
          Method -> "Queued"]}],
       Dynamic[
        ListPlot[traj[[;; tmax]], DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi*tmax/50}, 
         PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}, 
         PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], ImageSize -> 350],
        None,
        TrackedSymbols :> {tmax}]
       }]
     ]
```

2. Using the implicit update caused by changing a variable instead of the `Do[]` loop:

```
    DynamicModule[{tmax = 0, traj},
     traj = Sin@Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 50] ; (*the trajectory to plot*)
     Dynamic[
      If[tmax < 51, tmax++];
      ListPlot[traj[[;; tmax]], DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi*tmax/50}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
        PlotLabel -> Row[{"tmax = ", tmax, Button["Restart", tmax = 0]}]],
       None]
     ]
```

3. Using an `Animator` instead of a `Do[]` loop:

```
    DynamicModule[{tmax = 0, traj},
     traj = Sin@Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 50] ; (*the trajectory to plot*)
     Column[{
       Row[{
         Animator[Dynamic@tmax, {1, 51, 1}, DisplayAllSteps -> True, 
          AnimationRepetitions -> 1, 
          AppearanceElements -> {"ProgressSlider", "PlayPauseButton", 
            "ResetButton", "FasterSlowerButtons"}],
         " tmax = ", Dynamic@tmax}],
       Dynamic[
        ListPlot[traj[[;; tmax]], DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi*tmax/50}, 
         PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}, 
         PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], ImageSize -> 400], None]
       }]
     ]
```

4. Using `Animate`, localizing `traj` in a `DynamicModule`:

```
    DynamicModule[{traj},
     traj = Sin@Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 50]; (*the trajectory to plot*)
     Animate[
      ListPlot[traj[[;; tmax]], DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi*tmax/50}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05],
        ImageSize -> 400],
      {tmax, 1, 51, 1, 
       AppearanceElements -> {"ProgressSlider", "PlayPauseButton", 
         "ResetButton", "FasterSlowerButtons"}},
      DisplayAllSteps -> True, AnimationRepetitions -> 1
      ]
     ]
```

5. Using `Manipulate` and localizing `traj` inside it:

```
    Manipulate[
     ListPlot[traj[[;; tmax]], DataRange -> {0, 2 Pi*tmax/50}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 2 Pi}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], 
      ImageSize -> 400],
     {tmax, 1, 51, 1, ControlType -> Animator, DisplayAllSteps -> True, 
      AnimationRepetitions -> 1, 
      AppearanceElements -> {"ProgressSlider", "PlayPauseButton", 
        "ResetButton", "FasterSlowerButtons"}},
     {{traj, Sin@Subdivide[0, 2 Pi, 50]}, ControlType -> None}
     ]
```